# Do Indian passport holders with UK Tier 2 need to get a tourist visa for Mexico?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, mexico, visas-on-arrival

I'm an Indian passport holder currently resident in the UK under a Tier 2 (General) visa and planning on going to Mexico on a holiday. So I was looking into the rules on the Mexican embassy in the UK and [the following text on the "Visa for other countries nationals" suggests I don't need a visa in advance](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/en/contenido/108-visas-for-other-countries):

> According to the new regulations who entered into effect on 18th, May
>   2016 (article 26 of the Guidelines and Requirements for Migratory
>   Services) regarding foreign nationals visiting Mexico, **holders of a
>   valid UK visa, regardless their nationality, are not required to apply
>   for a Mexican visa as a tourist, business (Non-Lucrative Activities)
>   or transit visitors for a stay of up to 6 months**. This regulation does
>   not apply to British Travel Document holders.

However, [a different page on Indian national states only a category on visa exemption for permanent residents in the UK only](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/en/contenido/116-grupo-3):

> PERMANENT RESIDENT IN THE UK (ILR / ILE / PERMANENT RESIDENTS)
>
> According to Mexican regulations which came into force in June 2009,
>   Permanent residents in the United Kingdom wishing to travel to Mexico
>   do not require a visa to enter the country as tourists or business
>   visitors for up to 180 days and as visitors in transit for up to 30
>   days, regardless their nationality.

**So which one is correct?** Are Tier 2 holders with an Indian passport allowed visa-free / visa on-arrival entry to Mexico?

Comment: @pnuts "TIMATIC still seems to have the 2009 requirement" Wrong, see my answer

Comment: @pnuts That's the issue, you put the UK as the country of residence, in which case only the exemption for permanent residents shows (similarly, for the US, only the exemption for Green Card holders shows). If you do **not** put the UK as the country of residence, you'll get it

Comment: @pnuts To Timatic, visas (unless labelled "residence visa") are held by non-residents, whereas residents hold residence Permits. While this is obviously not always the case, this is how it's programmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=MX&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=VS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa exemptions:
>
> Passengers with a **valid visa** issued by Canada, Japan, USA, **United Kingdom** or a Schengen Member State a maximum stay of 180 days

So no, you do **not** Need a Mexican visa

Comment: Crazy how adding the country of residence changes things - thanks for clarifying!